Embedding a finite dimensional Manifold in an Infinite Dimensional Space
I am interested in whether it is possible to embed a finite-dimensional manifold, $M^n$, in an infinite dimensional real Hilbert space, $H$ (e.g. $l^2$) in a way that is "nontrivial" meaning there is no finite-dimensional subspace  $V \subset H$ which contains the embedding of $M^n$.
If this is possible, what about a compact manifold?

I imagine that $M=(0, 1/2)$ and the embedding $t\mapsto (1,t,t^2,t^3,\dots)$ will do

@user8268: that's quite nice! We can get an embedding of $S^1$ by modifying this idea a bit, say $S^1 \ni z \mapsto (1, \frac{z}{2}, \frac{z^2}{2^2}, \dots)$.
